# Branches are not pushed anymore in GitHub: why?

Tags: git, github

I have the following branches and commits of my project

[image: branches]

After the branch **70035d7** nothing is added in GitHub after typing the `git push` command.

Why is that?
How can I add the remaining branches?

Comment: Your branch names have changed. You are no longer pushing to `main` branch you are pushing to the `master branch` You need to switch to the `main` branch merge `master` to main and then push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your want your main branch to be where your master branch is, type:

```
git switch -C main master
git push
```

The push would then push everything since `origin/main`

Answer (score 1):

Fromw hat I can tell, you are on `master` branch. `git push` pushes to remote repo and only branch you are currently on, so you are pushnig `master` branch.

To push other branch, you need to switch to that branch and push:

```
git checkout main
git push
```